# My webapplication works fine when testing it in IDE, but doesnt work on webserver (tomcat) session is invalidated

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, deployment, war

In my project,i have set an attribute to session variable and accessing it in later part of the code.The session is maintained and everything works fine in eclipse.
But when i export the same as WAR file as run it,i have observed that a new session is created.So,the attribute is lost.I have kept req.getSession(true).

Not sure why the session is being invalidated in WAR scenario.I am using tomcat 7 .i have added the same tomcat instance in my eclipse environment.

Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: what is your goal, whenever you connect thru new client a new session will be created in server and maintains 30 min default

Comment: Yes,the session time out is set as 30mins in tomcats configurations.In our webapp,the session attribute is accesed before timeout only.

Comment: I am setting the session varaible in a JerseyServlet Class.In our webapp we are configuring a filter which is called everytime(URL Pattern (/*).In the JerseyServlet Class i retrive a value from database and set in session attribute.When the response is being rendered(Reponse.build()),further calls are made so it goes to dofilter method of the filter.Here,im accessing the session attribute.This is working fine when im running in Eclipse,But as War file the session is being invalidated and new session is getting created(tried to print session.getid).

Comment: My code goes something like this.

Comment: In my code we have to access a Sharepoint server and display the response in our web app.The sharepoint Url is maintained in the database.When the request comes for Sharepoint app.We fetch the sharepoint url from database and store it in session.Once the Sahrepoint is autheticated is responds with plain text(which has css,js,image relative paths.So,when we are rendering the response if the relative path is for js,css or image request goes through filter.Here we retrive the sharepoint url to ftech the sharepoint js/css/image data

Comment: This is happening properly in Eclipse IDE.but in WAR the session is invalidated.Any pointers are appreciated:)